# Grunt convert .png to .jpg files

Tags: node.js, web, gruntjs, png, jpeg

I was trying to find anything to convert my `.png` files to `.jpg` files in grunt, but I can only find `.png` compressions or converting `.pngs` and `.jpgs` to `.webp`.

Anyone any idea how to do that? I am using Node.js with AngularJS and Grunt.

**EDIT**

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('pngToJpg', 'Convert PNG files to JPG format', function() {

        const imagemin = require('imagemin');
        const pngToJpeg = require('png-to-jpeg');

        grunt.log.write('Loaded dependencies...').ok();

        imagemin(['images/*.png'], 'build/images', {
            plugins: [
                pngToJpeg({quality: 90})
            ]
        }).then((files) => {
            // Please keep in mind that all files now have the wrong extension
            // You might want to change them manually
            grunt.log.write('Loaded dependencies...').ok();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is such grunt plugin is available in the Grunt website, However you can install the **png-to-jpeg** convertor from npmjs.com at the below URL,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/png-to-jpeg

And can add them as a custom task to your `gruntfile.js`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I am not very familiar with custom tasks in grunt. I was trying to do it as above without success. Could you give me a little help?